# Capitalization in a series

Tags: writing-style

I *think* this is purely a style preference, but I want to confirm (and settle a debate amongst colleagues). In general, is it better to use:

Antioch, Oberlin, and Boston Colleges.

-or-

Antioch, Oberlin, and Boston colleges.

On another forum, I found that the AP would choose the latter in the case of lists of things like rivers and mountain ranges -- I assume the same goes for lists of things like academic institutions. I can't find a style guide that advises the former, but it's nearly impossible to find results on Google that answer the question (I'm not even sure what to put into the query..."capitalization of a series of proper nouns" doesn't do it).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd score the first one as just plain wrong. The AP advice seems the safest option, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

As a former Antiochian :) I wouldn't capitalize "colleges", it is not a name. Only exception: If this were a title, then I would capitalize it. (At least, that's how I've learned it.)

Answer (score 1):

Yale University has 'U' capitalized as it is part of its name similarly if 'Boston Colleges' is supposed to be the name of a group of colleges then I'd capitalize the 'C' otherwise I wouldn't.